# Change the font inside `tabular` globally, in LaTeX Beamer (metropolis)

Tags: tables, beamer, fonts, typewriter, beamer-metropolis

I have a presentation in `beamer` with the `metropolis` theme. All the content of all tables  should be written in mono/typewriter font. Ideally I would prefer to make the change globally, inside the preamble.

A workaround, which kinda works, but has to be set locally for each table, is to change the font inside the `table` environment. See the out-commented two lines.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

%\setmonofont{Courier Prime}  % (optional) more distinct typewriter font

\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Typewriter table}

This text should have the default Beamer font.

\begin{table}
  \caption{Default text font}
  %{\ttfamily  % workaround start: until the closed curly bracket, should be typewriter font
  \begin{tabular}{cr}
    \toprule
    Begin \textbf{typewriter} & \textit{mono} \textit{\textbf{font}} \\
    \midrule
    A    &  0.1   \\
    Bc   &  1     \\
    Cde  & 23.45  \\
    Defg &  3.456 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  %}  % workaround end
  \caption{Default text font}  % added to check both, top and bottom, description variants
\end{table}

This text should have the default Beamer font.

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Screencapture for the workaround
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

**Edit:**
After reading your comments below, your question is not entirely clear, what all are your problems. Anyway, please one problem per question. Now I add one possible solution for option for compiling with LuaLaTeX where is used `FiraSans` and correct first version, where is now used default Beamer fonts fonts.

Regarding `etoolbox`: it is needed at older LaTeX version. At recent one  definition for `\AtBeginEnvironment` is integrated in it (now I assume, that you have installed  recent LaTeX).

An example compiled with `pdfLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\ttfamily} % global setting for tabular


\begin{document}


  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Typewriter table}
    
    This text should have the default Beamer.
    
    \begin{table}
      \caption{Default text font} 
      \begin{tabular}{cr}
        \toprule
        Begin \textbf{typewriter} & \textit{mono \textbf{font}}   \\
        \midrule
        A       &  0.1   \\
        Bc      &  1     \\
        Cde     & 23.45  \\
        Defg    &  3.456 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \caption{Default text font}  % added to check both, top and bottom, description variants
  \end{table}

  This text should have the default Beamer font.

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Typewriter table}

  This text should have the default Beamer.
  
  \begin{table}
    \caption{Default text font}
    \begin{tabular}{cr}
    \toprule
    Begin typewriter & mono font \\     
    \midrule
    A       &  0.1   \\
    Bc      &  1     \\
    Cde     & 23.45  \\
    Defg    &  3.456 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

This text should have the default Beamer font.

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

An example compiled with `LuadfLaTeX` and using `FiraSans` fonts:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}    
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\ttfamily} % global setting for tabular


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Typewriter table}

  This text is in the FiraSans sans Serif fonts.
  
  \begin{table}
    \caption{Default text font}
    \begin{tabular}{cr} % in tabular are use \ttfamily as defined in FiraSans
      \toprule
      Begin \textbf{typewriter} & \textit{mono \textbf{font}}   \\
      \midrule
      A       &  0.1   \\
      Bc      &  1     \\
      Cde     & 23.45  \\
      Defg    &  3.456 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Default text font}  % added to check both, top and bottom, description variants
    \end{table}

This text should have the default Beamer font.

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Typewriter table}

  This text should have the default Beamer.
  
  \begin{table}
  \caption{Default text font}
  \begin{tabular}{cr}
    \toprule
    Begin typewriter & mono font \\
    \midrule
    A       &  0.1   \\
    Bc      &  1     \\
    Cde     & 23.45  \\
    Defg    &  3.456 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  This text should have the default Beamer font.

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

For defining use FiraSans font only for `\ttfamily` please ask new question.

Comment: Exactly what I thought of! (+1).

Comment: @Zarko: Thank You! This is very nice! Is `etoolbox` really required? If yes please comment why -- for me it works fine even without. If possible adjust the indentation inside the code in order be more readable. ... And correct my typo "Tyepwriter".

Comment: @Zarko: is there a possiblity to change the `\ttfamily` font only, when using `lmodern`? I've compiled with `lualatex` and `xelatex` and the loading of `lmodern` package changes all(!) default fonts of `metropolis` (Fira family).

Comment: @Zarko: continuation to the comment before:
 I've tried `\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}` instead of loading `lmodern`. However it doesen't preserve the boldface highlighting.

Comment: @alex you can use any monotype font which has bold and italic font. Yes, you can change `\ttfamily` font. Here on site are many questions (and answers) about this. Since I'm not expert for fonts, I need to search site to learn this, but this you can do yourself :-). About `etoolbox`: yes it is needed. Do you have problem to use it?

Comment: @Zarko: I've already upvoted your answer. (1) For `lualatex` compilation `etoolbox` is not required. Can you please check if your compilation routine works without it. Otherwise, please comment the line why`etoolbox` required. (2) Your solution changes all fonts, even the non typewriter ones! That's not what I asked. To actually change the setting in order to answer the question only the `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\ttfamily}` line is required. Please comment out with (optional) the lines which are not mandatory for solving the question. Than I can set your answer as the solution. Thank you.